# react-native-collapsible height not changing on adding some more view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-animations, react-native-collapsible

I have a [react-native-collapsible](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible) view, which render some of the components along with another `Collapsible` view.

My problem is that after collapse the view of `Collapsible` component, if I add some components which increase the height of the `Collapsible` view then `Collapsible` view is not increasing itself. It adjusts the components, I means its hide some of component and then displays the newly added components.

Here is some code :

```js
<Collapsible
    collapsed={!this.state.display}
    duration={500}
    align="center"
>
    <View>
        ...
        some component
        ...
        {/* Another Collapsible component */}
        <ToggleInputBox
            label="Description"
            value={this.state.description}
            onChangeText={(description) => this.setState({ description, status: 'unsaved' })}
        />
    </View>
</Collapsible>
```

Related issues :

[1. Collapsible Not Correct Height On Component View Update While Open](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/issues/278)
[2. Content height doesn't updating if content view updated.](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/issues/210)

How I can solve this issue ?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: @highjump try this: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-collapsible/issues/278#issuecomment-753793084 I have not found any other solution yet.